# How to get flex child to expand when one element is hidden with tranform?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am currently trying to learn how to use `display: flexbox` and I am trying to use it in a project that involves both main content and a sidebar that is hidden using the `transform` property.

However, the main content does not expand within the parent to the full width if the sidebar is hidden by a transform. How can I force the main content to go full width?

```
.parent {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1 1;
}

.hidden-child {
  background-color: green;
  transform: translateX(100px);
  width: 100px;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Crotanite/d2vwhnk5/

Comment: I'm confused, can you provide an image or some type of example of what you'd like the end result to look like

Comment: @Tigerrrrr apologies. If you take a look at the jsfiddle, the red should cover all of the blue, as the main content should stretch to cover the space the hidden child has left behind.

Comment: because transform is a visual effect only, it doesn't affect the layout

Comment: Like Temani said, the `.hidden-child` is still there it's being covered up

Answer (score 1):

Use [flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) to force the main content to take 100% of the width.
You can also use `white-space: nowrap` to prevent the child item to break into multiple lines.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1 0 100%; /* here */
}

.hidden-child {
  background-color: green;
  transform: translateX(100px);
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap; /* and here */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    child
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-child">
    hidden child
  </div>
</div>
```